# Error when using string.Join

Tags: c#, string

I'am loading a text file and displaying the textfile name in a listbox. And when I click the listbox im saving the path of the file to a variable. This works in another application of mine, but in the new application I get the following error :

> Error 8   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string,
>   string[])' has some invalid arguments Error   9   Argument 2: cannot
>   convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'string[]'

This is the code :

```
string fileloadpath;

private void FileListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var selectedItems = FileListbox.SelectedItems.Cast<FileItem>();                   

  var all = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path1));

  fileloadpath = all;
}
```

Edit : I added ToArray() at the end and that fixed it. Thanks guys.

I have one more error related to this :

When I display the file path in the listbox, instead of the actual file name(test.txt), the text is displayed as : "OpenCV.Form1+FileItem"

Here is the code :

```
void reciperefresh()
   {
       FileListbox.Items.Clear();

       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Recipe", "*.txt", 
          SearchOption.AllDirectories);

       foreach (string f in files)
       {
           var fileItem = new FileItem { Title1 = Path.GetFileName(f), 
            Path1 = Path.GetFullPath(f) };
           FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem);

       }
   }
```

Comment: what is type of `fileloadpath` ?

Comment: `.ToArray()` on the end of your query.

Comment: `selectedItems.Select(x  => x.Path1)` will return an `IEnumerable`. You need to call  `.ToArray()` on that select

Comment: Hi, adding ToArray() worked. I have one more query related to the same question. Have updated the main question.

Comment: @user3177511 I have updated my answer to address your second issue (which should really be a new question)

Comment: Apparently `String.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)` is available from .NET framework version 4.0 - Consult: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable` but the method requires a `string[]`. Add [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) after the Select.

```
var all = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path1).ToArray());
```

Re: the additional part to your question (which should really be a new question), you need to change it to:

```
FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem.Title1);
```

Otherwise it is using the `Object.ToString()` method which you are not overriding. Alternatively override the `ToString` method in your `FileItem` class.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @Owen

Comment: There is a new error now, when i click on any item in the list box it says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FileItem'."  File item is public string Title1 { get; set; } and public string File1 { get; set; }

Comment: It seems that this new error is because of using Title1 in FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem.Title1);  If I remove Title1, this new error goes away but the file name is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path1)` with `selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path1).ToArray()`. You should pass an array of strings instead of `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: I have one more query related to this, have updated the question.

Comment: @user3177511 override the `ToString()` method for your `FileItem` class. If I remember correctly it will be called automatically and will display in the way you write.

Comment: Thank you, both your method as well as @Owen's answer worked.

Comment: Hi, There is a new error now, when i click on any item in the list box it says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FileItem'." File item is public string Title1 { get; set; } and public string File1 { get; set; }

Comment: @user3177511 create new question and describe the problem with it's exception. And add there the Click event handler that you have

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an Array or Strings instead of the Enumerable that your selectedElements are.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are trying to use an enumeration of string instead of a string array. Try that:

`string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path1).ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. It is saying to convert it to array of string.